# Validity sensors ID 138a:0010

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb

I tried to get a working fingerprint reader on my laptop ASUS PRO B400VC-W3022X.

I've already managed installing/configuring `frpintd` following this article but It did not work for me, still showing:

```
wash4@wash4-NB:~/Stažené$ lsusb -s 001:005 -v

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing

wash4@wash4-NB:~/Stažené$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b375 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```